# get_as_dataframe convert N/A as NaN want to prevent it

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-sheets-api

I am using **gspread_dataframe** for reading google spreadsheet data. The problem that faced it converts N/A as NaN but I want to keep it as N/A

```
    wks = self.google_spreadsheet_connection.open("test")
    worksheet = wks.worksheet("data")
    df = get_as_dataframe(worksheet, index='false', evaluate_formulas=True)
```

I have already used `'keep_value_na=False'` but doest not worked for me.

Any help will be appriciate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.fillna('N/A')`. It will change NaN values with the 'N/A'

Another solution:

`na_filter=False`

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', na_filter=False)

     A    B    C
0  foo  bar  N/A
1  N/A  bar  foo
2  foo  N/A  bar
```

Comment: it will fill all the NaN to N/A but i need N/A only where it was

Comment: Oh i got it. I dont know why `keep_value_na=False` didnt worked for you but you can try `na_filter=False`. I created test data and it worked.

Comment: I have another idea, its a little primitive but maybe it can be useful for you. The idea is that if you are able to change the `N/A` values to something, just replace them with spesific string and after you read the dataframe you can replace them again to `N/A`